# Tons of errors when starting a virtual device

Tags: android, adt

I'm just starting with android (having programmed Java only in a text editor) and I would appreciate your input. I downloaded the ADT bundle as suggested, as well as some packages from the SDK Manager. Next I set up a Nexus 4 virtual device, with its default RAM value of 1907MB. Even after reducing the RAM to 768MB as suggested, I still get dozens of errors in the LogCat when launching the virtual device. However, using a different device I do not get all those errors?

So here are my questions:

1. Did I do something wrong? Is the Nexus series particularly bad to program for (the Nexus10 virtual device just shows a black screen...not even any errors, though the Nexus7 does seem to work)?
2. I have 16GB RAM, i7-2500K@4GHz, Samsung 830 SSD, clean Win7 x64, yet the emulator is quite slow. Is this normal (would be totally understandable) or is the virtual device smooth for everybody else but me?
3. Is the ADT bundle the way to go or should I have downloaded eclipse and the SDK separately?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Edit:** Posting only the first and last few of the errors (the log file with just the errors is ~45KB, 362 errors in total)

```
08-01 05:42:42.007: E/BatteryService(292): usbOnlinePath not found
08-01 05:42:42.007: E/BatteryService(292): wirelessOnlinePath not found
08-01 05:42:42.007: E/BatteryService(292): batteryVoltagePath not found
08-01 05:42:42.007: E/BatteryService(292): batteryTemperaturePath not found
08-01 05:42:42.109: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(292): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
08-01 05:42:42.317: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-01 05:43:21.147: E/SQLiteLog(292): (1) no such table: secure
08-01 05:43:21.597: E/SoundPool(292): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
08-01 05:43:21.597: E/SoundPool(292): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
08-01 05:43:21.857: E/EventHub(292): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
...
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-01 05:46:23.181: E/StrictMode(713):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Yes, the emulator is slow. You can save a snapshot to reduce subsequent startup times though, and there are alternative emulators.  And, post the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

1. I never had any problems with the virtual emulator, if N4 doesn't work pick another one, or use an Android device through usb.
2. It's slow no matter what you do, but if you use large image resources it becomes even slower because it has to pack everything inside the .apk, send it to the device and install it.
3. ADT Bundle is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to start Nex4 AVD ?? If not please try deleting it and create a new one with a bit lesser RAM say 700MiB.

Your answers,
 1.) As far as you mentioned, there seems nothing wrong. (Please post the LogCat o/p).
 2.) EMULATOR IS SLOW. but you tweak things to speed it up a bit. Here's what you do.

```
    i.) Enable Hardware Virtualization (Intel VT-x) in your bios.
    ii.) Open ADT -> SDK Manager. In the extras section, you can find the Intel HAXM.
    iii.) Check the package and Click "Install Packages".
    iv.) This just downloads the executable. Install it manually from "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\Intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\IntelHaxm.exe".
    v.) Go for default RAM allocation in installation. 
    vi.) Now when you create a new AVD, in Hardware section Set the flag "GPU emulation" to "yes"
```

3.) ADT is preferred way to go although its is no different than what you will have after installing SDK & IDE separately.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!

I am able to start the Nexus 4 AVD, but do get tons of errors during startup and when using the AVD. See my first post for some lines of the LogCat errors (I don't know what "o/p" means).

I did download the HAXM, but assumed it was installed (since that's what it said in the SDK Manager). Thanks for the tip! Any AVD still crashes when I set the RAM to more than 768MB, though. :(

The AVD does seem to run smoother with GPU emulation enabled (but still not perfect, obviously) - too bad that you can't use the snapshot functionality as well.